# How to Get error message from DB and display it in QGIS Plugin?

Tags: plugins, pyqt5, qt5, qgis

I am trying to create a Custom QGIS plugin where i connect the Db and execute the queries from a selected file. what I need is to display the usual error message which gets displayed in the DB while any error is raised during the connection and execution.
Please let me know any ways to get the traceback message and display it plugin, I have also referred to the scripts of the DB manager plugin also. but it seems difficult for me to get exactly how they did it.

Answer (score 0):

From this [link](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/db_manager/db_plugins/postgis/connector.py), try this one:

```
try:
  #your code here
except QgsProviderConnectionException as e:
  raise DbError(e)
```